# Crash while creating index

Tags: sql-server, crash, indexing

I have a table with 300 Million+ records in MSSQL and I need to create a new index. Crashes while creating index. Is this a good work around?

Currently crashes after churning for hours and hours on end (8+).

I thought about just creating a new table with the proper indexes and copying the data over. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: Why a tag "large-data" on something that is not even medium size? 300 million rows is not small, but really, large starts at many times that.

Comment: What does "crashes" mean? Also please don't make a 200-word title - that stuff belongs in the body of the question.

Comment: @TomTom doesn't that also depend on the width of the row? If every row is 8K I might disagree that we have the same definition of large.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Not really. I mean, the last big database we did had a LOT of rows - mostly numbers, but IIRC more than 100 fields, and we added 300 million rows or so per day on that particular table, storage for 2 years. Even 8k per row dont really put THAT into a different territory.

Comment: @TomTom but why do you get to define what "large" means? The tag wiki isn't even defined. And isn't it also relative to the capacity of the OP's hardware? I don't follow the reasoning behind the nit-picking. If you don't agree that the OP thinks it's large, <shrug>.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Quite well established. Large is at least more than Memory of a normal mid range Server, which is today 64gb. Anything that easily fits into Memory is not large. Very large is - hm - 100 times larger, when you have to start THINKING; not just coding. But something that easily fits into Memory is not large, and no, it is not about "How cheap can I go". 64gb is low end These days. Just building a MICRO ATX Server this week with 64gb.

Comment: @TomTom are you confusing "large data" and "Big Data"?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Hardly. I am definitely not confusing "small" with what we have here. Anything that fits into memory is not large. Point.

Comment: @TomTom if you feel that strongly about it, then remove the tag instead of nagging.

Comment: @TomTom why spend so much time and energy debating the relevant merits of the tag? you seem smart, put that energy toward answering the question.

Comment: I think you need to post your DDL for the table and the index.  While more memory can be better, the point of databases is to manage data far larger than any memory you could possibly have in a server and retrieve it in useful time, and that includes building indexes, although obviously some things take time.  I'd like to see the actual error message.  Are you building the index with a script or using the GUI?  This message comes after 8 hours of index building or somewhere in the log?

Comment: We do not need the DDL, we need a size assessment. And analyze what happens during those 8 hours. THis is a LONG time for a small operaiton like this, so it looks like somehting hits the disc a lot - I suspect either memory, or more concrete, tempdb overvlow (i.e. writing to physical disc). If you can keep it all in memory, a decent nont too old server should easily have 25+gb/s bandwidth - the moment it starts hitting the disc it is "good bye performance. So, find out WHAT discs it hits. May I assume the CPU is not really heavily taxed? And what server version, how many bits?

Answer (score 1):

that would depend on why it's crashing, if you're running out of disk space, making a new table won't help.  Look in the SQL logs and see if it gives any indication as to what's going on when trying to create the index.

Comment: +1. Believe it or not, 300 million are not a lot. I regularly query 50 million as RESULT from a table around 10 times as long. THere is a reason it crashes.

Comment: I understand it is not a lot. It crashes with an out of resources exception (memory).

Comment: @user1977683 Well, how much memory do you have? OBVIOUSLY if you want to play with real data, you need a real server. How big is this table, in gb, and how much memory do you have?

Comment: Yes, if you are hardware restricted, a new table isn't going to help you.

Comment: I have 24 gb of memory. Can do 74 if necessary, but really don't think it should need that much.

Comment: How large is the table? Is tempdb overflowing (showing tons of IO)? You may HAVE to do that. This is what Version (SQL Server) and 64 bit?